# Does Anaconda does not yet support Python 3.9.x?

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter, anaconda

I have downloaded and installed  Python 3.9.7 (the latest version to date) on my Windows. It is installed and working fine using command prompt or VS code. But Anaconda (I use Jupyter NB) still shows the older version ie 3.8x installed.

How can I resolve this?

Comment: You can update it yourself. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41536068/9420000) for a similar question